# Struggling to remove a reaction from specific user in discord.js. Says remove not defined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make pages work by reacting left or right. That works but I can't seem to undo the users reaction. It tells me remove is undefined

```
.then(sentEmbed => {
            sentEmbed.react("⬅️"),
                sentEmbed.react("➡️")
            const filterLeft = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '⬅️' && user.id === author;
            const filterRight = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '➡️' && user.id === author;
            const collectorLeft = sentEmbed.createReactionCollector(filterLeft, { time: 15000 });
            const collectorRight = sentEmbed.createReactionCollector(filterRight, { time: 15000 });
            collectorRight.on('collect', r => {

                currentMessage = sentEmbed.id,
                    client.channels.cache.get(channel).send(currentMessage),
                    sentEmbed.reaction.remove(author),
```

Comment: little typo: sentEmbed.reactions (with the s at the end)

Answer (score 1):

I supposed your are using discord.js v12. If yes, the reactions collected is now using caching. So you need to replace:

`sentEmbed.reaction.remove(author);` by `sentEmbed.reaction.users.remove(author);`